# How do you numerically sort an arraylist with int+string entries

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm working on a leaderboard and my data is stored in an ArrayList as

```
int + " " + username
```

I've been trying to sort it to display.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

    List<String> leaderboard = new ArrayList<String>();

    leaderboard.add("11 John");
    leaderboard.add("23 annie");
    leaderboard.add("1 putin");
    leaderboard.add("101 king");
    Collections.sort(leaderboard);

    for(int i = 0; i < leaderboard.size(); i++) {   
        System.out.print(leaderboard.get(i));
        System.out.println();
    } 

}
```

Outputs an alphabetical sort:

```
1 putin
101 king
11 John
23 annie
```

when I need

```
1 putin
11 John
23 annie
101 king
```

and to finish it off I would use

```
Collections.reverse(leaderboard);
```

To display it as a high score chart.

Comment: Make custom objects with a number and name as instance attributes.

Comment: Why `throws java.lang.Exception`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to treat the first part of the string numerically:

```
public class NumericalStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.split(" ")[0]);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.split(" ")[0]);
        int cmp = Integer.compare(i1, i2);
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

You could then use it to in a reversed order to sort your collection:

```
 Collections.sort(leaderboard, new NumericalStringComparator().reversed());
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. Works flawlessly thanks a lot!

Using his code I get the proper sort.

Thanks. Will accept as answer after 5 minute cooldown. Appreciate it.

Comment: This is only if you *need* the data to be stored as `String`s. You probably *don't*. The recommended solution is to either use a `Map<String, Integer>` (instead of the current `List`) to map `names` to their respective `scores`; or to create a custom object that effectivelly does the same "key-value" pairing. This is to avoid storing numbers as String (memory-inefficient) and having to parse them in/out of Strings (cpu-inefficient)